# Close turtle window by X button(close)

Tags: python, window, turtle-graphics

I'm coding Python and I'm learning Turtle. When I close turtle window by X button I'm getting an error. What can I do?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or copy paste the error.
Would also be nice to upload a link to Turtle.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`try` - `except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) block in each iteration of your `while` loop to detect
when the user clicks the X button.

When the click is detected, use `break` to break out of the loop.

From:

```
import turtle

while True:
    # Your game loop code
    turtle.update()
```

to

```
import turtle

while True:
    try:
        # Your game loop code
        turtle.update()
    except turtle.Terminator:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, errors generated upon closing the window via its buttons is due to abusing turtle's event module by using a `while True:` loop instead of timed events and other approaches.

If this the case with your program, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49587546/5771269) for a detailed example of how to go about designing your code properly.

I would avoid any solutions that involve wrapping your code in a `try:` expression to catch the `Terminator` error as that's a band-aid and not a proper design.  Consider:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def one_step():
    
    # do one iteration of useful stuff here

    screen.ontimer(one_step)


screen = Screen()

one_step()

screen.mainloop()
```